# Trying to play two sounds with some delay in uwp app

Tags: xaml, uwp

Hi I' m trying to play two sounds with some delay in uwp app on page intialization

I am trying Like this but it is mixed .how to achieve that.
C# Code

```
public L_Col_Act()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            mediaElement1.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Objectnamesmp3/colors.mp3");
            mediaElement1.AutoPlay = true;

            mediaElement2.Source=new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Objectnamesmp3/yellow color.mp3");
            mediaElement2.AutoPlay = true;


        }
```

Comment: How much time did you want to delay?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT after one sound complete then play another sound. at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> after one sound complete then play another sound. at once

You could play one sound first, and register [MediaElement.MediaEnded event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.mediaended.aspx)

In MediaEnd event handler, you could start to play another sound.

```cs
private void MediaElement_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     mediaElement2.Source=new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Objectnamesmp3/yellow color.mp3");
     mediaElement2.AutoPlay = true;
}
```